# UI Testing a C# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

For the past few hours I've been trying to write selenium tests for an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app. A few weeks ago we wrote integration tests for the API using WebApplicationFactory and that worked great:

```
namespace ContactBook.Tests.Common
{
    public class TestContactBookApp : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
    {
        public TestDb TestDb { get; set; }

        public WebApplicationFactory<Program> App { get; set; }

        public TestContactBookApp(TestDb testDb, string appContentRoot)
        {
            this.TestDb = testDb;

            this.App = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
                .WithWebHostBuilder(webHostBuilder =>
                {
                    webHostBuilder.UseContentRoot(appContentRoot);

                    webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        var oldDbContext = services.SingleOrDefault(
                                descr => descr.ServiceType == typeof(ContactBookDbContext));
                        services.Remove(oldDbContext);
                        services.AddScoped<ContactBookDbContext>(
                            provider => this.TestDb.CreateDbContext());
                    });
                    // Use random free TCP port for the Web server
                    webHostBuilder.UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:0");
                });
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.App.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

For Selenium although I am getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when trying to access the base url.

Here is my `SeleniumTestBase` class:

```
namespace ContactBook.WebAPI.SeleniumTests
{
    public class SeleniumTestsBase
    {
        protected TestDb testDb;
        protected IWebDriver driver;
        protected TestContactBookApp testContactBookApp;
        protected HttpClient httpClient;
        protected string baseUrl;
        protected string username;
        protected string password;
        protected string phoneNumber;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUpBase()
        {
            // Run the Web app in a local Web server
            this.testDb = new TestDb();
            this.testContactBookApp = new TestContactBookApp(
                this.testDb, "../../../../ContactBook.WebApp");
            this.httpClient = testContactBookApp.App.CreateDefaultClient();
            //this.httpClient.
            this.baseUrl = this.httpClient.BaseAddress.ToString();
            this.username = $"user{DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()[10..]}";
            this.password = $"pass{DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()[10..]}";
            this.phoneNumber = "+359886183166";

            // Setup the ChromeDriver
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
                chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

            // Set an implicit wait for the UI interaction
            this.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void OneTimeTearDownBase()
        {
            // Stop and dispose the Selenium driver
            this.driver.Quit();

            // Stop and dispose the local Web server
            this.testContactBookApp.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I used this page for reference to no avail:

[ASP.NET Core Integration Tests with Selenium](https://www.benday.com/2021/07/19/asp-net-core-integration-tests-with-selenium-webapplicationfactory/)

[Quick fix for integration testing with Selenium in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://blog-bertrand-thomas.devpro.fr/2020/01/27/fix-breaking-change-asp-net-core-3-integration-tests-selenium/)

In one previous project (I haven't worked on it personally) my colleges use `IHostBuilder` to achieve a test server like so:

```
namespace TaskBoard.Tests.Common
{
    public class TestTaskBoardApp<TStartup> : IDisposable where TStartup : class
    {
        private IHost host;

        public TestDb TestDb { get; set; }

        public string ServerUri { get; private set; }

        public TestTaskBoardApp(TestDb testDb, string appContentRoot)
        {
            this.TestDb = testDb;
        
            IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
            hostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
            {
                webHostBuilder.UseContentRoot(appContentRoot);
                webHostBuilder.UseStartup<TStartup>();
                webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    var oldDbContext = services.SingleOrDefault(
                        descr => descr.ServiceType == typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
                    services.Remove(oldDbContext);
                    services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(
                        provider => this.TestDb.CreateDbContext());
                });
                // Use random free TCP port for the Web server
                webHostBuilder.UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:0");
            });
            this.host = hostBuilder.Build();
            this.host.Start();
            var server = this.host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
            var serverAddresses = server.Features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
            this.ServerUri = serverAddresses.Where(a => a.Contains("http://")).FirstOrDefault();
            Debug.WriteLine($"Testing server started: {this.ServerUri}");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.host.Dispose();
            Debug.WriteLine($"Testing server stopped: {this.ServerUri}");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making a somewhat similar implementation just to get a `A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.` error message.

I would really appreciate if someone has done this before successfully to lend a hand!

Comment: You can try adding Startup file in .Net 6 to use your second method. In this way there will be `Public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder, IWebHostingEnvironment){// your logic goes here}`.

Comment: @Chen I don't think this will work as the project structure for .NET 6 apps is very different than previous .NET versions

Comment: @Chem I stand corrected, indeed copying the old style startup and program pair fixes the issue!